# How do Comma-separated expressions as condition in a for-loop work?

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements

I´ve seen a a few times already in answers and questions here on Stack Overflow, a comma-separated list as loop condition for a for-loop like : `for(int i = 0, int j = 0 ; i < 2, j < 4; i++, j++) { ... }`
. How does this work?

How does a comma-separated condition work in a for-loop in C? 
Like: 
`for(int i = 0, int j = 1 ; i < 5, j < 4; i++, j++) { ... }`

Isn´t this invalid because the condition needs to be *an* evaluated expression? How do the multiple comma-separated expressions get evaluated to one expression in the for-loop?

The mentioned expressions are enclosed by semicolons `; i < 5, j < 4;`, and this shall be the condition of the loop. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The syntax for a `for` loop with a declaration is ([6.8.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5)):

```
for ( declaration expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement
```

This

```
for(int i = 0, int j = 1 ; i < 5, j < 4; i++, j++) { }
```

doesn't parse because

`int i = 0, int j = 1 ;` isn't syntactically valid as a declaration (or any sentential form in C for that matter) but

```
for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < 5, j < 4; i++, j++) { }
```

would parse, because

```
int i = 0, j = 1;
```

is a valid declaration (with multiple, initializer-containing declarators) and

```
i < 5, j < 4
```

is a valid comma-operator-containing expression, as is

```
i++, j++
```

.

(Note that `i < 5, j < 4` has the same effect as just `j < 4` because comma expressions are evaluated left to right and the value of the final part is used, and since `i < 5` has no side-effect here, the whole expression is equivalent to just `j < 4`. You might have wanted `i < 5 && j < 4` instead.)

In the original form of the `for` loop (without a declaration) you have ([6.8.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5))

```
 for ( expression_opt ; expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement
```

and the semicolons are used to separate the 3 (optional) expressions.

In the declaration-containing form, the first semicolon is parsed as part of the declaration

```
for ( declaration expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement
```

.

Comment: @JohnBollinger How `i < 5, j <4` is evaluated? How does the comma work when using it between two expressions?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica Comma expressions are evaluated left to right and the value of the final part (the part is technically an assignment-expression) is used. Since `i < 5` in `i<5, j<4` has no side effect and its value is thrown away (only the final part's value is used), it can be optimized away. I've put it in the answer now.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica In `i++, j++` for the final expression, the final value is irrelevant. You can't erase the first part because it has a side-effect, and the side-effects there are all that matters, because the value of the last expression in `for` is thrown-away anyway.

Comment: Put aside the mistakes I made with the declaration of `j` and that the example was maybe not that sufficient to ask for; How the behavior would be if the first expression would have a side-effect? F.e.: `for(int i = 0,j = 0; i < 3, j < 4; i++,j++){}`

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica i < 3, j < 4 is a evaluated in order and the last value is used. That's all there is to it. i < 3 is evaluated and thrown away, then j<4 is evaluated and because it's the last sub-expression in a comma expression, its value is used as the value of the whole expression. The possibility of sideffects only affects optimizations, not semantics. `puts("hello"),puts("world"),puts("!")` will run the puts in order. `extern int x; if ((x,x,x,x,x,x)) foo();` will only fetch `x` once because the value of every `x` except the last one is thrown away.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica (A dumb compiler may fetch the `x` multiple times, but a smart one won't. Fetching a non-volatile `x` isn't an observable side-effect, though, so it's irrelevant if it's fetched once or a hundred times as far as program semantics are concerned.)

Comment: I still do not get it quite right. But If only the value of the last sub-expression is used for the condition and the values of the other sub-expressions are thrown away, why are then several expressions implemented and get evaluated in general? What is the benefit of using comma-separated expressions as condition?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica They're a hack which you can use the get around grammar restrictions like the last part of `for` being an expression. If you want to specify that multiple things be done after an iteration, you can't use several statements like `i++; j++;` because the change part for for needs to be an expression, but you can use `i++, j++` because that does the same thing while qualifying as an expression.

Comment: Ok, I did understand, that this a very hacky way to do multiple things after each iteration in the last expression of `for`. But why should I do this behavior in the middle expression, when only the value of the last sub-expression of this middle expression is taken for proofing the condition of the iteration? What is the use of `i < 3` when it takes no effect? It even do no change any object; no assignment or anything like an incrementation is done, so it does nothing. It is only getting evaluated but it does nothing.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica In the controlling expression of for, it's useless and an error unless you're trying to test a C parser or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

All the expressions in the comma-separated list are evaluated, but only the last expression is used for the for loop condition.  So in effect the i<5 condition is ignored, since it's not the last expression.